# CakePHP 3 - how to filter data (Collection) in combination with pagination?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, filtering, cakephp-3.x

The combination of Collection function (in my case 'filter') and paginate() causes a error. The simplified PHP code is below:

```
$rooms = $this->Rooms
    ->find('all')
    ->formatResults(function ($results) {
        return $results->map(function ($row) {
            //... 
            $row->free_booking=0;      
            if($someCondition) $row->free_booking=1;
            //...

            return $row;
        });        
    })
    ->filter(function ($booking, $key) {
        return $booking->free_booking == 1;
    });
$this->set('rooms',$this->paginate($rooms));
```

### The error is below:

> Error: Call to undefined method ArrayIterator::alias() File
>   .../public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php
>   Line: 174

---

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `filter()` on the query object, that will cause the query to be executed, and converted to a collection, and paginating collections isn't supported.

You should generally refrain from manipulating results (adding/removing entries) on PHP level if you're using pagination, this will almost certainly mess up your pagination, as the number of records on PHP level won't match the counted records on SQL level.

Move your filtering logic into the query instead, ie filter on SQL level.

Comment: The problem is in app performance. The application is very fast if used $this->set('rooms',$this->paginate($rooms)); and very very slow if used $roomSegments = $rooms->take($limit,$offset)->toArray(); $this->set('rooms',$roomSegments);. The application processes a large amount of data

Comment: @user3661042 I'm not saying that you shouldn't use pagination, I'm just suggesting that you should filter on SQL level instead of on PHP level.

Comment: @user3661042 If you add your code that creates `$someCondition`, then maybe I can add an example on how to do it with SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, this can not be done with SQL because the '$someCondition' is extremely complex. One of the parts of the '$someCondition' is also room price calculation and booking check.

Comment: @user3661042 I mean, SQL is generally able to do complex operations, and even very large, complicated queries can still be fast, but it all depends of course. Without seeing the calculations I can't really give you any further advice tho, all I can say is that filtering on PHP level will break your pagination, as you don't know about the total number of records, and thus the pagination calculations will be wrong.

Comment: @user3661042 if you are do filtering on client side, you will have to do your own pagination on client side as well. There is a array pagination adapter if I recally correctly, but that requires for you to fetch all the results at once.

Comment: If you want query pagination - use query filtering. If not, then fitler yourself and paginate yourself.